# Spring Data JPA Java - how to get the last 10 records from query and order by column

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

i have used spring jpa to get the last 10 rows in the db but i cant sort those 10 rows by column that is different from id column.
get the last 10 rows:

`Page<Vinyl> findTop10ByOrderByVinylIDDesc(Pageable pageable);`

how to get the last 10 rows sorted by price likes this sql:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10)Var1 ORDER BY price ASC;`

Answer (score 0):

Try below

`Page<Vinyl> findTop10ByOrderByVinylIDDescPriceAsc(Pageable pageable);`

Answer (score 0):

List findTop10ByOrderByPriceAsc(Pageable pageable);